# Coauthoring Not working in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

CoAuthoring is not working in SharePoint 2013 with Word 2010, second user who is opening the document gets message that its still exclusively locked by the first user.
I have already checked that following settings is enabled on the document library:

```
a. Versioning is enabled on library
b. Required checkout is set to disable
c. docx document is used for coauthoring
```

Following powershell is used for enabling coauthoring:

```
$site="http://vm-33305-02:2017/sites/impact"
$currentSite=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($site)
$currentSite.WebApplication.WebService.CoauthoringVersionPeriod = 0
$currentSite.WebApplication.WebService.Update()
```

please help if anybody has face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was the aspnecompatibilityenabled attribute was missing from servicemodel config in web.config which is required for co-authoring to work